# In wikipedia API second array empty

Tags: arrays, json, search, wikipedia-api

While retrieving JSON data the second array in the Wikipedia API is always empty why is it so?

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=opensearch&origin=*&search=javascript
```

Tried changing the search term but still, the second array is empty.
Please help with any alternate link or any parameters that I might be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch) the empty array should return the first line of the article. For some reason, the API returns an empty string. If you compare the response from the [Sandbox API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=opensearch&search=Hampi&limit=10&namespace=0&format=json) with the given response in the Example section on the documentation page you'll see that the error occurs in the API and not on your end.

**Update**
After some more reading, below the Example section there is a link to a bug report which explains why the descriptions are disabled: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T241437